How to infer parameter types using function overloading in ts
I want to implement a function that can infer the return type through different parameters.
The type can be inferred normally when calling directly, but when using a function to return parameters, the inference will be incorrect.
The following is the reloading code I have written:
export interface Option {
  init?: boolean
  test?: boolean
}

function getType(): string

function getType(option: Record<string, never>): string

function getType(option: Option & { init: true }): boolean

function getType(option: Option & { init: false }): string

function getType(
  option?: Option,
): Option extends { init: true } ? boolean : string

function getType(option?: Option): boolean | string {
  if (option?.init) {
    return true
  } else {
    return 'none'
  }
}

getType() // string

getType({}) // string

getType({
  init: true,
}) // boolean

getType({
  init: false,
}) // string

getType({
  test: false,
}) // string



function useGetType(opt?: Option) {
  return getType(opt)
}


// What should be inferred here is boolean
useGetType({ init: true }) // string ??? 



The problem is:
function getType(
  option?: Option,
): Option extends { init: true } ? boolean : string

The return type can never be a boolean. Why? Because Option can never extend {init: true}.
Let us ignore test field for a moment and think of only the init field. If we define an object with const m : Option = { init :false }, we cannot assign it to {init : true}. Hence the extension fails.
That is why:
function useGetType(opt?: Option) {
  return getType(opt)
}

can never return a boolean, because getType(opt) here cannot return a boolean.
I have setup a small demo to give you an idea:
export interface Option {
  init: boolean
}
export interface WithInit {
    init : true
}

//Check this type
type T = Option extends { init: true } ? boolean : string;

const m1 : Option = Math.random() > 0.5 ? { init : true } : { init : false };
const m2 : Option = { init : true };


const n1 : WithInit = m1; //will error out
const n2 : WithInit = m2; //will error out

Playground
This gets inferred well because here there is no indication that argument will be of type Option.
getType({
  init: true,
})

So it matches with:
function getType(option: Option & { init: true }): boolean


Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I would like to know my current needs. Is it currently not supported by ts?

No. What you say is not possible in a type checking system. See what you are asking for is if Option extends { init: true }. This will always have one value, that is false. The type Option is not dependent on the value option. The types are defined way before the code actually executes and the values fill in right. So, no matter what you pass as option, if you are telling that its type will be Option then TypeScript is correct to understand the types it has done currently.
